# discontinuities in first derivatives of PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, continuity, partial-derivative

In the lecture notes (Oxford University, Applied Partial differential equations) it says that $u$ is continuous and only first derivatives of $u$ may be discontinuous across some curve $C$ in the $(x,y)$-plane, while $u$ itself is continuous there. The curve is defined by $(x(t),y(t))$.

**Since $u$ is continuous across $C$, so is $\dot{u}$.**

I don't understand this? Surely, if $u$ was continuous but had a "corner", which occured along $C$, its derivative wouldn't be continuous?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The discontinuity is "across" $C$, i.e., in the "normal" direction to $C$.  The derivative in the "tangential" direction must be continuous.  The picture is something like $u(x,y)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $u(x,y)=x$ for $x\geq 0$, the curve $C$ is the $y$-axis and of course the $y$-direction derivative is continuous either side.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!